# Dell Laptop without Service Tag and Tpm

Tags: bios, tpm, dell-g3

I have the laptop Dell G3 15 3500. One day it start showing windows blue screen.
When it starts a message appear with "ENTERING MANUFACTOR MODE". "No service tag is detected" ... "The service tag has not been programmed. This system will not function properly without a service tag", "Alert! TPM device is not detected"

I have reinstalled bios a lot of times and still service tag is not available.
I have entered to bios to enable Secure Boot, overwrite service tag, aactivate Intel Platform Trust Technology . but none of those changes are saved and when I enter again to BIOS setup, they are not saved.

I known what is my service tag, let say that it is A12B34. But I was unable to install it.
**How can I solve this issue?**
Note: system running windows 10